# Getting bitmap. android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS

Tags: android, bitmap, android-contentresolver

I'm trying to get bitmap with picked image uri.

```
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(path));
```

I get this

```
requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS or android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is in using new intent action

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), REQUEST_PICK_IMAGE);
}
else {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("image/jpeg");
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PICK_IMAGE_KITKAT);
}
```